# Verify 2 SQL Server linked servers to Oracle are equal

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am migrating SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012. 
One of the items to migrate is a linked server to oracle. The configuration of server, DNS, firewall, etc are not on my side. 
I need to make sure they are configuring the correct linked server, pointing to the correct database (we have many copys of databases). 
What Query can I run in both sql servers to identify the Oracles servers and databases are the same?

Comment: how is oracle connected to your question?

Comment: @Simon the linked server is targeting an Oracle, I am thinking in a query to the oracle to get the unique identification I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can show all linked servers from the `sys.servers` table on each of the server instances.

```
select * from sys.servers;
```

The linked Oracle server will be listed under:

```
product = `Oracle`  
and provider = `OraOLEDB.Oracle`
```

Comment: Yes, but this information isn't enough. I will get that I have a linked server pointing to "myServer", but if firewall and DNS are misconfigured this "myServer" could be different (actually that is my case and I am requiring to get this fix, so now I want to know a good way to validate this).